# How to put <div> and </div> before and after a block of content using append()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So what I'm trying to do is to add an outside div container by append  first, then content, then append  last. But the result seems to be that the  I added at the beginning closed itself by automatically inserting a . Results in two separate divs.

Anyone? Thanks!

```
//adds the outer div tag here...
$('#aspcal tr:eq(' + loopweek + ') td:eq(' + loopday + ')')
     .append("<div id='outer' style='height:15px'>");

//adds the inner content here...
 for (l = 0; l < rssArray.length; l++) {

if (eleArray[l][19] == curNumMonth 
     && eleArray[l][20] == curNumDay 
     && eleArray[l][21] == curNumYear) {

    $('#aspcal tr:eq(' + loopweek + ') td:eq(' + loopday + ')')
       .append("</br><div style='height:auto'><b>" 
               + eleArray[l][8] 
               + "</b></br><a href='" 
               + eleArray[l][0] 
               + "' target='_blank'>" 
               + eleArray[l][1] 
               + "</a></div>");
}

//adds the outer div closing tag here...
$('#aspcal tr:eq(' + loopweek + ') td:eq(' + loopday + ')').append("</div>");​
```

Comment: On the client, you don't work with HTML tags. You work with whole DOM nodes that be moved around in the DOM tree structure as a whole. jQuery lets you think you're actually manipulating HTML strings, but you're not. It just lets you use HTML strings to represent your structure. This confuses people.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create the `DIV` object first, append content to it, then append the `DIV` to your `#aspcal` table. Like this:

```
  //Create the DIV...    
  var myDiv = $("<div id='outer' style='height:15px'></div>");

  //add the inner content...    
  for (l = 0; l < rssArray.length; l++)
       if (eleArray[l][19] == curNumMonth && eleArray[l][20] == curNumDay && eleArray[l][21] == curNumYear) {
          myDiv.append("</br><div style='height:auto'><b>" + eleArray[l][8] + "</b></br><a href='" + eleArray[l][0] + "' target='_blank'>" + eleArray[l][1] + "</a></div>");
       }
  //add the div here...
  $('#aspcal tr:eq(' + loopweek + ') td:eq(' + loopday + ')').append(myDiv);
```

Answer (score 7):

You are not creating tags with jQuery, you are creating DOM objects.  A `div` is represented by opening and closing tags, plus attributes, etc, but is parsed and stored by the browser as an object in a data tree.  jQuery, and ultimately javascript, is simply telling the browser to create a new object in the tree.

You should create your outer div, and then append content to it.  jQuery will do the hard work for you.

```
//adds the outer div tag here...
$('#aspcal tr:eq(' + loopweek + ') td:eq(' + loopday + ')').append("<div id='outer' style='height:15px'>");


//adds the inner content here...
for (l = 0; l < rssArray.length; l++) {
    if (eleArray[l][19] == curNumMonth && eleArray[l][20] == curNumDay && eleArray[l][21] == curNumYear) {
        $('#outer').append("</br><div style='height:auto'><b>" + eleArray[l][8] + "</b></br><a href='" + eleArray[l][0] + "' target='_blank'>" + eleArray[l][1] + "</a></div>");
}
```

I only reference `#outer` in the selector, because as an ID, it should be unique.  If it isn't, change it to a class and do this:

```
//adds the outer div tag here...
var aspcal = $('#aspcal tr:eq(' + loopweek + ') td:eq(' + loopday + ')');
aspcal.append("<div class='outer' style='height:15px'>");


//adds the inner content here...
for (l = 0; l < rssArray.length; l++) {
    if (eleArray[l][19] == curNumMonth && eleArray[l][20] == curNumDay && eleArray[l][21] == curNumYear) {
        aspcal.find('.outer').append("</br><div style='height:auto'><b>" + eleArray[l][8] + "</b></br><a href='" + eleArray[l][0] + "' target='_blank'>" + eleArray[l][1] + "</a></div>");
}
```

If you already have content created, you can use `.wrap('<div>')` to add a div (or any other parent-able object) around your content.

Comment: *"jQuery is smart enough to close tags and do all of the hard work for you."* It doesn't close any tags. It either takes your markup, and uses `createElement` to create a new DOM node, or it uses `.innerHTML` to create DOM nodes (for more complex HTML strings). The fact that it uses HTML as syntax just makes you think you're/it's doing string manipulation.

Comment: Thanks Jeff, but I just found out that .wrap does its job but does not really apply nicely for my case since it's hard to find a appropriate selector for the inner content. And for the part where you mentioned that append() closes the div automatically. That's actually the problem since once it's closed, it will not contain the following contents. I found creating an empty div first and then do the appending works very nicely atm. Thanks anyways for the help.

Comment: @eastboundr: hence the rest of my answer.

Comment: @am not i am:  Yes, I am aware of how it works.  Some people, like myself, think more visually.  I should have put "close all of the tags" in quotes.  More of a metaphor for what is really going on.

Comment: I don't doubt that you know what goes on, but plenty of people don't and therefore treat the DOM like they're working with text on the server. This can be bad. Unfortunately parts of jQuery's API help continue that misconception. +1 on your update.

Comment: True enough.  jQuery is great because it masks a lot of the ugly under-belly of javascript cross-compatibility issues and such, but can make people ignore fundamentally what is really happening.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer, because that's up jQuery works...
Have you tried creating the empty div and then appending to that div?

```
var theDiv = $("<div id='outer' style='height:15px'>");
for (l = 0; l < rssArray.length; l++) {
     if (eleArray[l][19] == curNumMonth && eleArray[l][20] == curNumDay && eleArray[l][21] == curNumYear) {
         theDiv.append("<br /><div style='height:auto'><b>" + eleArray[l][8] + "</b></br><a href='" + eleArray[l][0] + "' target='_blank'>" + eleArray[l][1] + "</a></div>");
    }
$('#aspcal tr:eq(' + loopweek + ') td:eq(' + loopday + ')').append( theDiv );
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how the append API works. I would make your content as a variable, and then it simply becomes `$(targetselector).append('<div>' + variable + '</div>')`. Could also use `.html()` which would have the same result.

The main difference is that instead of adding all your content the way you're currently doing it, you would just keep concatenating a string.

Since you're concatenating a string, the divs could just be a part of it, even, and then you just `.html(variable)`

Comment: No worries. The other methods ultimately have a bit more potential to be flexible as they append a node at a time. Easier to mix and match different nodes if you ever need to do that.